# How can I assign new classes to each item in a list by iterating over a dictionary's key/value pairs based on a matched attribute in python?

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary, for-loop

Every existing object in this list needs to be replaced with an instance of a specific class.  Each existing object already has a .type which should pair with a key in a dictionary to produce the appropriate class (value in dict).  Objects then also need to regain their original .name from before class assignment.

I can't find a way to do this that doesn't involve nested for-loops, but nested for loops are basically assigning to EVERY member of a class the same name (the last name saved to a temporary variable).

I've dug through all of the basic literature and understand the fundamental logic surrounding loops, dictionaries, and lists, I'm just (sure that I'm) executing something improperly or nesting something the wrong way.

```
class gameObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = name

#Class given to any living thing in the game; confers basic stats
class livingThing(gameObject):
    def __init__(self, name="Living Thing", HP = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.HP = HP
        self.alive = True
        self.safe = True
        self.listready = False

# After livingThing, classes narrow into more specific groups that have unique traits, abilities, and roles in the game

class Animal(livingThing):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.truename = ""
        self.type = ""
        self.listready = False
        self.type = "Test"
        self.truetype = ""
        self.hasatype = False


class Reptile(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.therm = "ecto"
        self.type = "Game Reptile"

class Amphibian(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.therm = "ecto"
        self.type = "Game Amphibian"

class Bird(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.therm = "endo"
        self.type = "Game Bird"

class Mammal(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.therm = "endo"
        self.type = "Game Mammal"

class Fungus(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.therm = "none"
        self.type = "Game Fungus"

class Fungus(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.therm = "none"
        self.type = "Game Fungus"

class Ascomycetes(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.therm = "none"
        self.type = "Game Ascomycetes"

somereptile = Reptile()
somereptile.type = "Reptiles"
somereptile.name = "Some Reptile"

somefrog = Amphibian()
somefrog.type = "Amphibians"
somefrog.name = "Some frog"

somefungus = Fungus()
somefungus.type = "Fungi"
somefungus.name = "Some Fungus"

secondfrog = Amphibian()
secondfrog.type = "Amphibians"
secondfrog.name = "Second Frog"

thirdfrog = Amphibian()
thirdfrog.type = "Amphibians"
thirdfrog.name = "Third Frog"

secondfungus = Fungus()
secondfungus.type = "Fungi"
secondfungus.name = "Second Fungus"

dummypop = [somereptile, somefrog, somefungus, secondfrog, thirdfrog, secondfungus]


### PROBLEM FUNCTION ###
def givetype(poplist):
    typedict = {
    "Reptiles" : Reptile(),
    "Amphibians" : Amphibian(),
    "Birds" : Bird(),
    "Mammals" : Mammal(),
    "Fungi" : Fungus(),
    "Ascomycetes" : Ascomycetes()
    }


    holderlist = []
    tempnames = []
    i = 0

    for org in poplist:
        holderlist.append(org)
        tempnames.append(org.name)
        for key in typedict.keys():
            if (holderlist[i].type.lower() in key.lower()):
                holderlist[i] = typedict[key]
                holderlist[i].name = tempnames[i]
                print(holderlist[i].name,
                                holderlist[i].type)
                        i+=1

    return holderlist


dummymaster = (givetype(dummypop))

for animal in dummymaster:
    print(animal.name, animal.type)
```

I expect to produce:

```
Some Reptile Game Reptile
Some Frog Game Frog
Third Frog Game Frog
Second Frog Game Frog
etc
```

What I'm getting is:

```
Some Reptile Game Reptile
Third Frog Game Frog
Third Frog Game Frog
Third Frog Game Frog
etc
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why are you iterating over the dictionary keys?

Comment: The dictionary keys correspond (roughly) to the types of the organisms (e.g. a key might be "Reptile" and the type might be "Reptiles").  I'm looking to try and assign classes (which are stored in the values) appropriately based on overlap between types and keys.

Comment: ok, i also don't understand what you're doing with `i` and `tempnames` -- it looks like you only ever access the entry corresponding to the current organism, so why use the list?

Comment: That's one of my many attempts at trying to resolve the problem I mentioned above (i.e. every Amphibian ends up with the same name).  It appears that the last time the function is run, it assigns *every* object with the same type to have the same .name.  For loops *should* only iterate over each element once, but something in that code seems to be reaching multiple instances of a class in one sweep.

Comment: see my answer -- you only ever *create* one object of each type, so, whenever you modify it, all references to it reflect that modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only ever create one instance of each class (which happens when you create `typedict`), so all references to that instance (which is what `holderlist` is populated with, as opposed to distinct instances) will certainly all have the same name.

Try not instantiating classes in `typedict`, and instead doing the instantiation when you need it in the `for` loop:

```
typedict = {
"Reptiles" : Reptile,
"Amphibians" : Amphibian
... 
}
...

     holderlist[i] = typedict[key]()
```

Comment: That worked like a charm--thanks so much!  I can't believe it was something so simple.  O.O